# Haskell and random numbers

Tags: haskell, random, monads

I've been messing with Haskell few days and stumbled into a problem.

I need a method that returns a random list of integers ( Rand [[Int]] ).

So, I defined a type: `type Rand a = StdGen -> (a, StdGen)`. 
I was able to produce `Rand IO Integer` and `Rand [IO Integer]` ( `(returnR lst) :: StdGen -> ([IO Integer], StdGen)` ) somehow. Any tips how to produce `Rand [[Int]]`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

How to avoid the `IO` depends on why it's being introduced in the first place. While pseudo-random number generators are inherently state-oriented, there's no reason `IO` needs to be involved.

I'm going to take a guess and say that you're using `newStdGen` or `getStdGen` to get your initial PRNG. If that's the case, then there's no way to completely escape `IO`. You could instead seed the PRNG directly with `mkStdGen`, keeping in mind that the same seed will result in the same "random" number sequence.

More likely, what you want to do is get a PRNG inside `IO`, then pass that as an argument to a pure function. The entire thing will still be wrapped in `IO` at the end, of course, but the intermediate computations won't need it. Here's a quick example to give you the idea:

```
import System.Random

type Rand a = StdGen -> (a, StdGen)

getPRNG = do
    rng <- newStdGen
    let x = usePRNG rng
    print x

usePRNG :: StdGen -> [[Int]]
usePRNG rng = let (x, rng') = randomInts 5 rng
                  (y, _) = randomInts 10 rng'
              in [x, y]

randomInts :: Int -> Rand [Int]
randomInts 0 rng = ([], rng)
randomInts n rng = let (x, rng') = next rng
                       (xs, rng'') = randomInts (n - 1) rng'
                   in (x:xs, rng'')
```

You might notice that the code using the PRNG gets pretty ugly due to passing the current value back and forth constantly. It's also potentially error prone, since it'd be easy to accidentally reuse an old value. As mentioned above, using the same PRNG value will give the same sequence of numbers, which is usually not what you want. Both problems are a perfect example of where it makes sense to use a `State` monad--which is getting off topic here, but you may want to look into it next.

Answer (score 11):

You are recreating [MonadRandom](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom) on Hackage.  If this is more than just an experiment to see if  you can do it, you might want to use that library instead.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to get an *infinite* list of `Integer`s you're going to run into problems as you won't ever get a `StdGen` value back out. What you want to do here is `split` the `StdGen` first, pass one half out again and 'use up' the other half  to generate an infinite list of integers. Something like this:

```
infiniteRandomInts :: Rand [Int]
infiniteRandomInts g = (ints, g2) where
    (g1,g2) = split g
    ints = randoms g1
```

However, if you then repeat this approach to get an infinite matrix of `Integer`s (which you seem to want, by using `Rand [[Int]]`), you might run into problems of a statistical nature: I don't know how well `StdGen` deals with repeated `split`ting. Maybe another implementation of `RandomGen` might be better, or you could try to use some sort of diagonal walk to turn a `[Int]` into a `[[Int]]`.

Answer (score 3):

Using monadic notation, you should be able to write something like

```
randomList gen = do
    randomLength <- yourRandomInteger
    loop gen (randomLength + 1)
 where
    loop gen 1 = gen
    loop gen n = do { x <- gen; xs <- loop gen (n - 1); return (x:xs) }
```

And with this

```
randomInts :: Rand [Int]
randomInts = randomList yourRandomInteger

randomLists :: Rand [[Int]]
randomLists = randomList randomInts
```

Concerning the monadic computations itself, take a look at [this article](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Hierarchical_libraries/Randoms#Using_QuickCheck_to_Generate_Random_Data). Note that random generators are pure, you shouldn't need any `IO` just for this purpose.

Comment: the moment when you ask for a sample, you get in the IO monad