# Generate a random integer in a range in Haskell without a seed

Tags: haskell, random

How can I generate a random number in Haskell from a range (a, b) without using any seed?

The function should return an Int and not an IO Int.
I have a function X that takes and Int and other arguments and outputs something which is not an IO.

If this is not possible, how can I generate a seed using the Time library and the generate a random number in the range with the mkStdGen ?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2738824/570689 - nice answer for similar question

Comment: It sounds like the best you can hope for is `randomInt lo hi = lo` or something of that kind.  Without some kind of seed or IO the function has to return the same value every time.  And the lower bound is as random as any other `Int`. :)

Comment: "Anyone who considers arithmetical methods of producing random digits is, of course, in a state of sin." Attributed to John Von Neumann _in_ Knuth, D. _The Art of Computer Programming_, vol 2, p. 1 (1981).

Comment: I believe the best way to get a random number in Haskell with no IO or seed value is using [a function like this](http://xkcd.com/221/).

Answer (score 47):

A function cannot return an `Int` without `IO`, unless it is a pure function, i.e. given the same input you will always get the same output. This means that if you want a random number without `IO`, you will need to take a seed as an argument.

Using the `random` library:

- If you choose to take a seed, it should be of type `StdGen`, and you can use `randomR` to generate a number from it. Use `newStdGen` to create a new seed (this will have to be done in `IO`).

  ```
   > import System.Random
   > g <- newStdGen
   > randomR (1, 10) g
   (1,1012529354 2147442707)
  ```

  The result of `randomR` is a tuple where the first element is the random value, and the second is a new seed to use for generating more values.
- Otherwise, you can use `randomRIO` to get a random number directly in the `IO` monad, with all the `StdGen` stuff taken care of for you:

  ```
   > import System.Random
   > randomRIO (1, 10)
   6
  ```

Comment: For those doing this, don't forget `import System.Random`!

Answer (score 6):

Without resorting to all kinds of unsafe practices, it is not possible for such a function to have type `Int` rather than type `IO Int` or something similar. Functions (or, in this case, constants) of type `Int` are pure, meaning that every time that you "invoke" the function (retrieve the value of the constant) you are guaranteed to get the same value "returned".

If you want to have a different, randomly chosen value returned at every invocation, you will need to use the `IO`-monad.

In some occasions, you may want to have a single randomly produced value for the whole program, i.e., one that, from the program's perspective behaves as if it were a pure value. Every time you query the value within the same run of the program, you get the same value back. As the whole program is essentially an `IO`-action you could then generate that value once and pass it around, but this may feel a bit clumsy. One could argue that, in this situation, it is still safe to associate the value with a top-level constant of type `Int` and use `unsafePerformIO` to construct that constant:

```
import System.IO.Unsafe  -- be careful!                                         
import System.Random

-- a randomly chosen, program-scoped constant from the range [0 .. 9]            
c :: Int
c = unsafePerformIO (getStdRandom (randomR (0, 9)))
```

Comment: Especially, don't do this without carefully reading the advice and precautions mentioned at http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/System-IO-Unsafe.html.

Comment: @dblhelix Your link is dead

Answer (score 2):

```
fmap yourFunctionX $ randomRIO (a, b)
```

or

```
fmap (\x -> yourFunctionX aParam x anotherParam) $ randomRIO (a, b)
```

The result will then be of type `IO whateverYourFunctionXReturns`.

If you `import Control.Applicative`, you can say

```
yourFunctionX <$> randomRIO (a, b)
```

or

```
(\x -> yourFunctionX aParam x anotherParam) <$> randomRIO (a, b)
```

which you may find clearer

Answer (score 2):

Note that you can get an infinite list of random values using the IO monad and use that `[Int]` in non-IO functions. This way you don't have to carry the seed along with you, but still need to carry the list of course. Fortunately, there are plenty of list processing functions to simplify such threading, and you can still use the `State` monad in complicated cases.

Also note that you can easily convert an IO Int to an Int. If foo produces an IO Int, and bar takes an Int as its only parameter and returns a non-IO value, the following will do:

```
foo >>= return . bar
```

Or using do notation:

```
do 
    a <- foo
    return $ bar a
```

Or using `fmap` (monads are functors, and `<$>` is an infix version of `fmap`):

```
bar <$> foo
```

Answer (score 0):

I used SipHash for that purpose

```
import Data.ByteArray.Hash
import Data.ByteString (pack, cons)
import Data.Word (Word8, Word64)

random :: Word64 -> Word64 -> [Word8] -> Double
random a b cs = (subtract 1) . (/(2**63)) . read . drop 8 . show $ sipHash (SipKey a b) (pack cs)
```

the read and drop 8 and show serve the purpose to drop a newtype that doesn’t (or didn’t when I implemented this) support any casting

now you want an Int in a range. Integer is easier though:

```
random :: Word64 -> Word64 -> [Word8] -> (Integer, Integer) -> Integer
random a b cs (low,high) = let
    span = high-low
    rand = read . drop 8 . show $ sipHash (SipKey a b) (pack cs)
    in (rand `mod` span) + low
```

of course, you’ll still get the same number for the same arguments every time, so you’ll need to vary them ie you still pass around arguments, just not returned values too. Whether that’s more convenient than a monad depends (for my purpose it was)

this is how I made sure arguments (specifically the [Word8] argument) would always be different:

```
foo bytes = doSomethingRandom bytes
bar bytes = map (\i -> foo (i:bytes)) [1..n]
baz bytes = doSomething (foo (0:bytes)) (bar (1:bytes))
```